# How to remove tmp directory on git checkout?

Tags: git

I have rendered cached templates inside `tmp` directory. I have to clear the folder manually whenever I use `git checkout` or `git pull`. Can I configure git to do it automatically for me and all the users that are using repository?

I am using `ember-cli` with `broccoli` to manage assets. Broccoli is compiling templates and store them cached inside `tmp` directory that is not part of git repository. My team members can edit templates and I can pull the changes from git. The cache is usually outdated afterwards, because it is not a part of repository. At the moment I have to clear it manually. It is tiresome. I want to have it done automatically. I could define aliases to git commands but it is only an ugly workaround.

Comment: Can you not just use the .gitignore file to ignore all contents of the directory?

Comment: @tpbowden I have `.gitignore` but cache will have incorrect files inside after switching branches.

Comment: If you do `git ls-files` does it list files from the `/tmp` directory?

Comment: @JohnJesus No, it doesn't. Please see updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git has hooks which are triggered after certain events. It sounds like you could use the `post-checkout` and `post-merge` hooks to clear out your assets. It might not solve all problems but it could save you a few seconds in certain cases.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Answer (score 0):

Cache files shouldn't be part of the repository so you should exclude them from your repository.

To clear the cache you could use a deployment system like [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/) or Travis and execute commands on your server where you can clear the cache and make some checks before you pull your changes.

Ok to clear you cache you can very simple write a batch or bash file where you execute all commends after another.

Comment: Cache is not part of git repository. I have the problem on my local server.

Comment: Write a bash or batch file i don't know which system you use and run all commands so make a pull and then remove the folder then you can use that file to deploy.